# Jquery Date Picker On Multiple Input Fields

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page in which there are multiple input fields that is fromdate and todate. I have created dynamic ids and name. I have used jquery date picker.

[image]

Code:

```
<?php
  $i=1;
  foreach($locations as $location)
  {

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $location['name'];?></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtFromDate_<?php echo $location['pk_locationid'];?>" class="field" style="width:80px;" id="txtFromDate_<?php echo $i;?>"/>
</td>
    <td>
<input type="text" name="txtToDate_<?php echo $location['pk_locationid'];?>"  class="field" style="width:80px;" id="txtToDate_<?php echo $i;?>"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtFromTime_<?php echo $location['pk_locationid'];?>"  class="time-pick field" style="width:80px;" />
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="txtToTime_<?php echo $location['pk_locationid'];?>"  class="time-pick field" style="width:80px;"/>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <?php
$i++;
    }
   ?>
```

Jquery code For Date Picker:

```
(document).ready(function(){
        var count=0;
        count=<?php echo count($locations);?>;

        for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
        {
            var dates = $('#txtFromDate_'+i+', #txtToDate_'+i).datepicker({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                var option = this.id == "txtFromDate_"+i ? "maxDate" : "minDate";
                var instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
            }
    });
        }
```

Jquery Date Picker is displayed for fromdate and to date fields. In the above code i have applied the from date to date validation i.e. to date should be greater than from date.

The problem with above code is that this validation is applied on the last row only.

I want that this validation should be applied to all the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You redeclare the `dates` variable at every iteration of the loop. So when the loop is done, the `dates` variable that you're using in the onSelect handler is equal to last item that was set in the loop.

**Update** Try this code:

**Update2** One more thing is the issue of variable `i`. Its current value is available while in the loop, so later on, when the onSelect handler is used, the i has a value as in last iteration. To overcome this, you have to put `i` in a context of another function, that's why I have wrapped code in the body of the loop in another function to which I'm passing `i` variable.

**Update3** And one more thing - the logic for picking the option (minDate or maxDate) had to be reversed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;
    count=<?php echo count($locations);?>;

    for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
    {
        (function(i) {
            $('#txtFromDate_'+i+', #txtToDate_'+i).datepicker({
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                    var option, otherPicker;
                    if (this.id == "txtFromDate_"+i) {
                       otherPicker = $("#txtToDate_"+i);
                       option = "minDate";
                    } else {
                       otherPicker = $("#txtFromDate_"+i);
                       option = "maxDate";
                    }
                    var instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
                    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat ||     $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    otherPicker.datepicker("option", option, date);
                }
            };
        })(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks wtk for replying . can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: i have applied the suggested code but its not working that is to date can be selected with less than from date.

Comment: Sorry for the mixups. There was one more bug - I've update the code.